# Problem rotating image with MOUSE_MOVE

Tags: actionscript-3

Hey gang.  Stumped on something.

I have a disc I am rotating with the mouse with event.MOUSE_MOVE, like a jog wheel on some audio equipment.  Everything almost works as expected, but the problem I am experiencing is that the disc always jumps to the point where the user clicks on the disc.  I need the point on the disc that the user clicks on to remain under the mouse while the user spins the disc but I can't seem to come up with the correct math to make it happen.  Here's the code i am using:

```
var xd = (_knob.x  - _stageRef.stage.mouseX);
var yd = (_knob.y  - _stageRef.stage.mouseY);
var radAngle = Math.atan2(yd, xd);
_knob.rotation = int(radAngle * 360/(Math.PI * 2) - 90);
```

**_knob** is a vector circle wrapped in a movieclip, with the circle centered on the movieclip's reg point.  **_stageRef** represents the main stage.

Any help would be awesome.  I've scoured the interweb and can't come up with anything.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting _knob rotation to the angle between _knob and mouse cursor. So if rotation was 0, and angle 45, rotation becomes 45, therefore it jumps. What you need is measure *changes* in this angle, not setting it instantly:

```
var _mouseAngle:Number;

function getMouseAngle():Number
{
    var xd = (_knob.x  - _stageRef.stage.mouseX);
    var yd = (_knob.y  - _stageRef.stage.mouseY);
    return Math.atan2(yd, xd);
}

function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    _mouseAngle = getMouseAngle();
}

function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var newAngle:Number = getMouseAngle();
    _knob.rotation += (newAngle - _mouseAngle) * 180.0 / Math.PI; //EDIT: forgot to convert into degrees
    _mouseAngle = newAngle;
}
```

(Code not tested)

Comment: I see where you are going here but it doesn't seem to be working.  Doesn't angle have to be converted back into radians to use against the rotation property?  This line seems to be lacking that:  _knob.rotation += newAngle - _mouseAngle;  I tried implementing your suggestion but it currently undulates back and forth rather than rotating.

Comment: You can't have a void function that returns an int. Meaning: function getMouseAngle():void should be function getMouseAngle():Number. I have edited your answer to match this.

Comment: i saw that on his answer and changed it in my tests.  didn't occur to me to edit his answer :P

Comment: Yes, atan2 gives angle in radians, and rotation must be in degrees, hence the undulation. I said it's not tested :) How it goes with conversion applied?